# Android - Infinite HorizontalScrollView - Left or Right?

Tags: android, scroll, infinite-scroll, horizontalscrollview

[image: a busy cat]

(Green border is a smartphone)

I have a horizontal scroll view filled with 5 images. I want now a snapping infinite horizontal scroll view. I want to move left or right. Always filled at the start or end with the same image (with snapping).

The code structure looks like this:

```
 <HorizontalScrollView
android:id="@+id/hs"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:fadingEdge="none" 
android:scrollbars="none">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/image1" />

    //...

</LinearLayout>
```

I tried so many variations without success.

Or is a horizontal scroll view the bad choice?

Comment: I think, Horizontal scrollview is a bad choice, Use GridView with 7  items.

Comment: And in GridView.. can I move left or right?